# Promotion of sql scripts to dev, cert,staging and prod

Tags: java, spring, git, jenkins, web-applications

There are three deployment environments at my work namely DEV, CERT and PROD.

As of now, there is no process set up for promoting sql scripts from one env to the next. However, there are discussions to create a process where the dev team would commit the scripts to git and Jenkins job would fetch & execute the scripts in the respective environment during the build. I don't have more info on this to share. Anyway!

Right now, we are just committing the scripts for different bugs, feature sets into the respective git branches for safekeeping and shares a set of scripts with the DB team for a specific release. But there have been instances where a team member misses to share the script with DB team, forgets to commit/save the SQL in the project, etc. causing a deployment failure

I would like to know what would be a better way to promote scripts from one ENV to another with my current setup.

Looking forward to having a good discussion where anyone who is facing a similar challenge at work gets right directions

Current tech stack: SPRING, GIT, JENKINS, APACHE, JIRA

Answer (score 1):

For that there are tools for this cases, I would suggest to use one of the :

1. [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)
2. [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/)

Both are open source tools for sql management.

Comment: Great! But that's easy to find. I am looking forward to understanding different ways of handling the scenario from an enterprise application development perspective.

Comment: @stack123 I work in a big big solution, and we use flyway for this situations, the tool is very great and helpful, you need just to know how to use it.

Comment: I understand that when database change management needs to be in vendor-independent databases, these tools are better options. I'm not too familiar with liquibase but had done a minor reading on it. So basically, we'll have a master changelog file and .sql / xml files for respective features/bugs and when the application starts, the database configured will get updated to be in sync to the queries created in the changelog file. Is that correct?

Comment: @stack123 because you are using Jenkins, you can create a job to execute the scripts in the different environments, like this you can make sure that all the env are in the same version, also if the job fail in dev env then fix the script, and deploy again

Comment: Sure. That's what we are planning to do. I thought I would get more different possibilities from the group if I share my tech stack. Anyway!